# How to Center Table Using Bootstrap Framework

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, alignment, text-align

I'm making some changes to my static website, adding a payment gateway, so I'm adding a custom button created with paypal. The problem is that the table does not align center of the page as the rest of the content on the page. This is in the support page. Here's part of the code generated by paypal for the button... here's the link to the page
http://www.jvits.co/support.html

```
   <table>
<tbody><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Get Remote Tech Support">Get Remote Tech Support</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
  <option value="Tech Support 1">Tech Support 1 $60.00 USD</option>
  <option value="Tech Support 2">Tech Support 2 $120.00 USD</option>
  <option value="Tech Support 3">Tech Support 3 $180.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center the table by using the Bootstrap class "mx-auto":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">

<table class="mx-auto">
<tbody><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Get Remote Tech Support">Get Remote Tech Support</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
  <option value="Tech Support 1">Tech Support 1 $60.00 USD</option>
  <option value="Tech Support 2">Tech Support 2 $120.00 USD</option>
  <option value="Tech Support 3">Tech Support 3 $180.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```